# Can I change the db connection pool size dynamically?

Tags: mysql, spring, kubernetes, rdbms, apache-commons-dbcp

We are preparing to migrate the spring 4 based legacy service to Kubernetes, also known as K8s.

Since rdbms is used, there is a limitation that the number of connection pools must be fixed at startup.

However, we want to use the auto scale function of k8s, but the problem is that the method of changing the pool size variably at runtime does not come up easily.

I am using dbcp2, is there any possible solution?